# Port manipulation using C code

Tags: programming, c

I'm trying to manipulate the ports of Arduino using C code. I have attached an LED to pin 8 and a tact switch to pin 13 (with a pull down resistor). The code works fine, and the results are printed on the screen. So, when the button is pressed, the byte `PINB & (1 << PB5)` equals 32, or `0b00100000`.

However, if I try to use

```
if( PINB &(1<<PB5) == 32){
```

or

```
if( PINB &(1<<PB5) == 0b00100000){
```

the LED doesn't respond.

Here's the full code:

```
void setup() {
  DDRB |= 0b00011111; 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }

void loop() {
  Serial.print("PINB &(1<<PB5)");
  Serial.println(PINB &(1<<PB5));

  if( PINB &(1<<PB5) ){
    PORTB |= (1<<PB0);
    }
  else{
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0);    
    }
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you saying the full code you've posted works, but it fails if you add `== ...`?

Comment: That's right , it fails with ==                             .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` has higher precedence than `&`, which means that your comparison will be performed incorrectly. But that doesn't matter, since you don't need to check if the port has a *specific* value, just if the appropriate bit is set.

Comment: You are right. If I use `my_byte = PINB &(1<<PB5)` and   `if( my_byte = 0b00100000 ){` it works fine. Nevertheless, could you explain how the comparison with `==` and `&` works? Thank you.

Comment: Not really sure what needs to be explained. `a & b == c` is equivalent to `a & (b == c)`.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thank you again.

Comment: I found another solution based on your last remark. `if(  (PINB &(1<<PB5) ) == 0b00100000){  ` works too

Comment: Eh. Like I said, you don't need to care about the exact value.

Comment: That's right, I just want to understand how it works

Comment: What @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is trying to say, is that you can remove the `==` part all together. Just use `if( PINB &(1<<PB5) ){ `. As all values other than 0 are truthy.